# jQuery - Apprise not working in ajax loaded division

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am attempting to utilize apprise [link](https://github.com/ThrivingKings/Apprise) on my website. I have a webpage on which I include the apprise javascript and css files. I also include my own javascript file containing the following function

```
function cant_find(data)
{
    Apprise('Modal test');
}
```

I am utilizing jquery `$.load()` to load another page into a division on the page.
This works perfectly.

Within the callback of the load, I call my function

```
$('#div').load(base_url+'link',{},function(data){
    cant_find();
});
```

This however does not work and gives the error:

`$Apprise is null`

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see `$Apprise`, but the url you linked to seems to indicate that it's the lower-cased "apprise," not "Apprise."

Comment: http://thrivingkings.com/read/Apprise-v2-The-new-and-improved-attractive-alert-alternative-for-jQuery The examples utilise $Apprise..